# How to change this image in this Wordpress custom theme?

Tags: wordpress

When I go into the .php file, I see the img src listed like this:

```
src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id_page )); ?>"></p
```

How do I update what the image displays on the site? I can just insert the direct link to the image, but I assume it was written that way for a reason, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would post this as a comment rather than an answer but it is too long for that*

What you see is a **PHP query**.

If you change that into a **hard-coded link**, *all the pages that use that template - or php file - will end up using the image you link to instead of their own images*

**WordPress is a dynamic system.**

This means that you don't have to create the full page every time you create a new post. it's template based. Most of the code is reused and re-purposed for different pages. Only the content changes. The recyclable code is stored in the PHP files.

**The content in this case is the image** you referred too. The **PHP Database query** I mentioned earlier checks what **image is associated with that page** and **returns the hard-coded link in HTML format**.

What are you trying to edit / change?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - makes sense. I was able to figure out what page the featured image was pulling from and updated it there. I was so confused because I just hadn't seen a theme built this way before! Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The post thumbnail is derived from the **featured image** of a post/page.

Look for featured image section when you're composing your post/page. It is usually at the right side of the editor page.

As the function suggests, it will automatically get the thumbnail version of the image you set as the featured image of the page.

Should you not be able to find featured image section on your editor page, expand the options by clicking on the button at the top right corner and make sure that featured image is checked.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was able to find the page that had the featured image that was being pulled, since it was from somewhere different than the page itself. Thanks for your help!